# Cannot find namespace

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) when challenged with a problem in one of my applications. I understand the usage, but cannot find the namespace for the `local` element where we find `local:SetterValueBindingHelper.PropertyBinding`. So what namespace does this reference? `Google` has not found the class either, nor `MSDN`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Local` just means an alias for a namespace in your own (or someone else's) code. E.g. say you took the SettingValueBingingHelper and saved it in your project, in the namespace MyNamespace. To use it in xaml you would reference the namespace by adding to your UserControl (or Page)

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"
```

It does't have to be `local` - it could be named anything that is relevant to your code, e.g. `helpers`.

Another example would be using the Triggers from System.Windows.Interactivity - you would reference the namespace:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;
          assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and then use the triggers in your xaml:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

BTW, the link in your original post has been [updated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx).

Comment: I left a comment on that blog and they explained the helper class they were using and now it makes sense.